# Nginx rewrite .aspx url to new Laravel route

Tags: laravel, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I'm trying to migrate an aspx project to new Laravel Project.

I want to convert and redirect old site links to new site links.
If an user comes from Google or old links.

old url : /tr/detail.aspx=pageId=596
new url  : /old-url/detail/596

I tried below code but nothing helped.

```
    location / {
    rewrite http://cu.test/tr/detail.aspx?pageId=(.*) http://cu.test/index.php?$query_string permanent;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    server_name  cu.test;
    listen       80;

    location /tr/detail.aspx {
        rewrite ^/tr/detail.aspx /old-url/detail/$arg_pageId last;
        set $args "";
    }
    location ~* /old-url/detail/(\d+)$ {
         return 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt worked when i try it's downloading a  'detail '  page `code    server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name cu.test;
    root "/home/vagrant/cu/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location /tr/detail.aspx {
        rewrite ^/tr/detail.aspx /old-url/detail/$arg_pageId last;
        set $args "";
    }
    location /old-url/detail {
         return 200;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }  `

Comment: I forgot a slash, try again

Comment: Thanks, It worked but redirected to  `/old-url/detail?pageId=19`   It must be `/old-url/detail/19`  I think line with started location with try_files add query_string but i need it in laravel porject for the other routes.

Comment: @Yilmazerhakan retry

Comment: Sorry i couldnt retry, because my nginx doesnt reflect new changes, it's showing old settings now. I changed with an error and must give error but doesnt reflect and works!!! if i fix this error will try your last solution. Thanks.